# Crypt information in a file

Tags: java, encryption

I'm developing a desktop application, and I have a login form which the user has to fill in order to access the application.

In this login form I have a `JCheckBox` which is `"Remember me"`.

When the user enters his ID and Password and then check the `"Remember me"` `JCheckBox`, I want the program to crypt this ID and Password then to save them in a file.

My question is: how can I crypt those data? And if I crypt them and then I want to read them from the file, am I have to decipher them?

Comment: Do not encrypt passwords.  Instead, you should store a limited-use token signed by the server.

Comment: When a password is entered, how is it used by the application? Is there a server component?

Comment: There's no solution to this short of a "key store" implemented by the OS (which is do doubt vulnerable, but less so).  Otherwise you'll end up doing "security by obscurity".

Comment: @SLaks I can't understand what do you mean

Comment: @LewisDiamond it's a simple application which has to remember the used if he checked the "Remember Me" JCheckBox, I don't know what you mean by server componenet

Comment: why not just remember that the user has authenticated himself (maybe with an expire time) ?

Comment: @AzerRtyu You need to give a clearer definition of what your application does and how it handles authentication and authorization. It doesn't seem like you are in a position to provide any kind of security.

Comment: Why don't you use a one-way encryption, similar to the unix crypt()? You don't need to decrypt, just encrypt what the user enters and compare with the encrypted string stored on regisration.

Comment: @AzerRtyu - Please do not implement such security system in an application unless you are competent in the field and always use well known and proven implementations. You may want to rely on the OS to identify the user. Do not encrypt the password on disk using a key that you store (anywhere). If a two way encryption scheme is used, do not store the key and always ask the user for it (you can keep the session active for X min). You should store password using a hash + salt scheme (and make sure it is not writable by anyone else. Remember, system administrators will always have full access).

Comment: @AzerRtyu: Lewis Diamond is extremely correct.  If you can't understand my comment, you need to learn more about security and cryptography before you start writing anything like this.  Security is _hard_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is not to encrypt/decrypt a username/password since it can be broken.
Anyway here is a java code example that you can use to encrypt/decrypt your data. It use the [AES][1] algorithm.

*Warning: This code keep the secret key inside the java class which is not a secure way to store the key, because anyone who have access to this class will be able to view it and use this key to decrypt your encrypted information. The key should be stored in an external file.*

```
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

    public class CipherUtil {

        private static Base64 coder;
        // linebreak
        private static byte[] linebreak = {}; // Remove Base64 encoder default
        private static String secret = "qhebp92ihc13g741"; // secret key length must
        // be 16
        private static SecretKey key;
        private static Cipher cipher;

        static {
            try {
                key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "AES");
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
                coder = new Base64(32, linebreak, true);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static synchronized String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
            return new String(coder.encode(cipherText));
        }

        public static synchronized String decrypt(String codedText) throws Exception {
            byte[] encypted = coder.decode(codedText.getBytes());
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encypted);
            return new String(decrypted);
        }
    }


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard
```

Comment: Note that `private static String secret = "qhebp92ihc13g741"` will be available to anyone who actually wants to get it. I.e. the encrypted file is completely insecure, even worse, the application gives a false sense of security.

Comment: @LewisDiamond I agree with you, this is only a code example to show how to use the Chipher to encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: @fmodos - I suggest adding a clear notice at the top of your answer to warn people who would use this thinking it is a secure scheme.

Comment: @fmodos - Note that storing the file in plain text in an external isn't secure either, especially on windows systems (system passwords can be easily cracked). Unless the file is encrypted (encrypting they key file with, yet another key?), anyone with physical access to the machine can retrieve the key and decrypt the passwords, making this scheme awful. Many people use the same passwords on several services/apps, with access to this file, you can know the plain text password and access other resources using it.

Comment: Nobody should do what is suggested here, ever. The key should be provided by the user. (unless this application resides on a server, but in this case you wouldn't want to use the same key with every user, you'd instead generate new keys that would be transmitted using a public-private-key scheme).

Comment: @LewisDiamond again I agree with you, the point here is that we dont know what is the scope of his system. His main question was "how can I crypt those data? And if I crypt them and then I want to read them from the file, am I have to decipher them?". I was just being objective showing the code example that he asked for. Please post an answer with this whole security model and code examples that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have quite enough details for an accurate answer but I'll give it a shot.

Firstly, do not encrypt the password locally because that means your application has to also decrypt it, hence it will hold the symmetric key in memory and make it vulnerable.

If you need to locally validate a user's password, use a one-way hashing function with salt. Note that this means you will have to write a plain-text file to disk which isn't secure (people could modify the password hash if they have write access to the file). To overcome that, you'd need to use a symmetric encryption scheme and require the key each times you read/write the file. This won't prevent people from corrupting the file either.

If you're talking about a client-server application, generate a temporary token on the server and implement some expiry mechanism.

Comment: I'm not developping a client-server application, and the user it's the only one who has access to that file, because his computer is locked.

Comment: Then why does he need a password?

Comment: because the application is installed on all computers, so if he owns that computer but he isn't allowed to enter to the application he won't if he hasn't a login and a password.

Comment: @AzerRtyu, Then store the token in the same place as the username and password.